How to get rid of the IsolateThread argument
I'm trying to pass a function pointer in a structure to a C library (FUSE). The prototypes of the functions are defined by the library, so I don't have the chance to change them.
The problem is that graalvm require to have an IsolateThread parameter. I found a github that uses those annotation to get rid of it:
@CEntryPoint
@CEntryPointOptions(prologue = CEntryPointSetup.EnterCreateIsolatePrologue.class,
                    epilogue = CEntryPointSetup.LeaveTearDownIsolateEpilogue.class)
private static void idle() {

I had to add this dependency to have this annotation available:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
            <artifactId>svm</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

But then I can't compile at all (I use the shade plugin of maven to include all my dependencies):
Error: Processing jar:file:///net/172.18.192.1/c/Users/edaniel/IdeaProjects/java-hdfs-fuse/target/java-hdfs-fuse-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/native-image/org.graalvm.truffle.compiler/native-image.properties failed
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError: Failed to process ForceOnModulePath attribute: Module descriptor for the module org.graalvm.truffle.compiler could not be resolved with class-path entry: /net/172.18.192.1/c/Users/edaniel/IdeaProjects/java-hdfs-fuse/target/java-hdfs-fuse-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
Caused by: java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /net/172.18.192.1/c/Users/edaniel/IdeaProjects/java-hdfs-fuse/target/java-hdfs-fuse-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: jnamed.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)


Opening the jar and removing the problematic files, I get this error:
Fatal error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class jdk.graal.compiler.hotspot.HotSpotGraalJVMCIServiceLocator (in unnamed module @0x2dc54ad4) cannot access class jdk.vm.ci.services.JVMCIServiceLocator (in module jdk.internal.vm.ci) because module jdk.internal.vm.ci does not export jdk.vm.ci.services to unnamed module @0x2dc54ad4
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.defineClass(NativeImageClassLoader.java:490)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.findClassViaClassPath(NativeImageClassLoader.java:442)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageClassLoader.loadClass(NativeImageClassLoader.java:629)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)


So I'm wondering where I'm doing something wrong ?

Okay, after few days I got it to work.
Adding the svm dependency is the good way to go.
But you mark it as provided. And for the compilation to work, you must use the exact same version of the dependency as your GraalVM JDK version.
Not the Java version, but the GraalVM version.
❯ $JAVA_HOME/bin/native-image --version
native-image 21.0.5 2024-10-15
GraalVM Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.5+9.1 (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-jvmci-23.1-b48)
Substrate VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.5+9.1 (build 21.0.5+9-LTS, serial gc, compressed references)

Here we can see (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-jvmci-23.1-b48), jvmci 23.1. So :
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
            <artifactId>svm</artifactId>
            <version>23.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

